# Does Eclipse compile out unused local variables?

Tags: java, eclipse

Consider the following code:

```
 public String foo(){
      String bar = doStuff();
      return bar;
 }
```

And then later:

```
 public void test(){
      doSomeLogicHere();
      String result = foo();
 }
```

Note that in `test` I get a String named `result` at the end of the function. Eclipse knows this is an unused variable, as it warns about it. What I'm wondering is, do these Strings get compiled out as if the call was just `foo()` without saving the returned String? If I commented out `String result =` when I'm not using it would I reduce memory consumption or does it not matter since the String is still generated and returned in `foo()`?

I have some debugging logic in an application I'm writing like this, and I'm wondering if it's worth it to comment out all of the Strings for a release/when I'm not using them.

Comment: you actually have two unused variables here - foo and bar. Your second line of test() could just say doStuff(). If the code doesn't get optimised out, the memory allocation would be on the stack (not the heap) for the two local variables (bar & result) and they would get allocated and de-allocated at absolutely minimal cost.

Comment: Isn't this a bad example? the `foo()` method might actually be doing something important, but we just don't use its result.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, compiler doesn't automatically remove unused variables. That's usually the job for optimizers/obfuscators.

For instance, in Android [ProGuard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) removes all unused variables when you build your android app in release mode.

Comment: Oh considering this is an Android application, I suppose the answer is I don't have to worry about it because ProGuard will remove it.

Answer (score 1):

The `result` assignment won't make any difference performance wise: the Java JIT in the JVM will optimise away these unused variables in nearly all cases.

I personally fix these kind of things just to keep my code clean and warning-free.

Comment: So it's not compiled away, per say, but at run time it's "just in time compiled" JIT so that the difference of whether I left it or not is negligible.

Comment: Yep that's basically the gist. Although I think it's implementation-dependent whether the original Java compiler bothers to remove the assignment (it doesn't matter, since the JIT will do it anyway). Some may do this: if you're interested you can check the generated bytecode to be sure.